# django model choices is not populating the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following code:

```
class ReportType(models.Model):
    REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('E', 'Earnings'),
        ('MA', 'Monthly announcement'),
        ('WA', 'Weekly announcement'),
        ('SA', 'Sales announcement'),
    )
    report_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default="Earnings"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.report_type
```

This is just one of the model classes which includes a choices attribute for one of the fields. However, when doing "makemigrations" and then "migrate" the management tool creates the database table but does not populate the database table attribute with the data in the choices which it should do. The result is that when I'm using this model in a modelfrom I get an empty drop-down list when clicking on the dropdown box in the form.

This problems occurs on almost everyone of the model classes which includes the choices field, but one of the model classes is actually working, but it has the same code except from different content in the actual choices.

Does someone know why the django management tool is not populating the data in the choices attribute into the database table ? I cant see any problems with the code.

EDIT:
Modelform for the Report class:

```
class ReportForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['profile', 'name', 'report_type', 'time_period', 'link']
```

The ReportType does not have a modelform attached to itself, but it is a foreignkey in the Report class.

The Report model has this code:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    report_type = models.ForeignKey(ReportType)
    time_period = models.ForeignKey(ReportTimePeriod)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    report_conclusion = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="No conclusion yet")
    market_reaction = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="No market reaction yet")
```

The ReportTimePeriod also has a list of choices in one of the attributes so I would expect it to populate the database there as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the database tables. In fact for most database engines, it never stores the choices at the database level. The choices are typically only verified, etc. at Django level.

Comment: Can you share a sample `ModelForm` you use?

Comment: Hmm ok. When looking at the model where the choices are being populated in the database.. in the modelform code it refer to it directly while the ReportType does not have a modelform..it is just being linked from Report with a foreignkey. So i suppose you need to have a direct relationship here and that it doesnt work with tables that are just foreignkeys. Then you would need to write scripts that actually populate the database with the necessary values instead of just using the choices attribute for CharField.

Comment: it indeed stores the *choices* you make for records, but the column definition does *not* store the possible choices, these are typically *not* enforced at database level. If you use a `ModelForm` then normally it should work. If it works with a "vanilla" `Form`, you should add a `ChoiceField`, etc.

Comment: I do not really understand why you here use a `ReportType` model with a choices. Typically you either add such field at the `Report` class itself, or you allow `ReportType` to have "free" text.

Answer (score 3):

You are misinterpreting how things work, the `ModelForm` for your `Report` model will look for `ReportType` instances to pre-populate the select in the html template. You need to create `ReportType` instances first.

Judging by your `ReportType` model and your question I assume you think that Django will create one `ReportType` instance for each of the `REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES` yet this is not the case. The `choices` attribute in a field is there for validation purposes. If you want to keep your models like they are now you'd need to create one instance of `ReportType` per `REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES` value.

Now, unless you have a good reason to have a `ReportType` model, you could change your `Report` model in the following way:

```
REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('E', 'Earnings'),
    ('MA', 'Monthly announcement'),
    ('WA', 'Weekly announcement'),
    ('SA', 'Sales announcement'),
)

class Report(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    report_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=REPORT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default="E"    # note we use the Key here
    )
    time_period = models.ForeignKey(ReportTimePeriod)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    report_conclusion = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="No conclusion yet")
    market_reaction = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="No market reaction yet")
```